# Filling up a 2d vector containing scruct

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, struct, fill

I have a small struct containing a bool, char & two ints. But when I try to run this code, I get into a problem.

```
struct Struct
{
  bool check;
  char display;
  int x,y;
};

typedef vector<Struct> Array;

vector<Array> Matrix;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    vector<Struct> temp;

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        temp[i].push_back(Matrix);
    }

    Matrix.push_back(temp);
}
```

I want to fill my 2D array so that I would later be able to write something in terms of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {

            Matrix[i][j].display = '*';

    }

}
```

However, as of now, I get the error:
"temp has no member push_back()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring `temp[i]`. As temp is not an array or a vector of vectors it can't be used like that. When you do `temp[i]` you are getting the `i'th` element of vector temp, which is a `Struct`, which has not a `push_back` method.

You can do something like this to initialize the `Matrix`:

```
....
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    vector<Struct> temp;

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        Struct s;
        s.check = true;
        s.display = 'c';
        s.x = i;
        s.y = j;  
        temp.push_back(s);
    }

    Matrix.push_back(temp);
}
....
```

Comment: I understand, thank you. Would it be possible to create such a 2D array ? I'm still not sure of how I would fill up my array.

Comment: What is your final necessity? To have a 2d array of `Struct`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to be able to give certain positions in my `Matrix[i][j]` values which are contained in `Struct`. I was able to do it by `#define SIZE` and then `Matrix[SIZE][SIZE]`. However, I need my matrix size to be dynamic, and this is where I run in to the issue with filling the array.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you !

Comment: Great! You go on and accpet the answer that helped.

Comment: Almost forgot ! ^^

Answer (score 1):

As the above answers have already mentioned you are trying to call `push_back()` on `Struct` type rather than on `std::vector<Struct>` type, so your compiler is complaining the same. Try below:

```
void initMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        Array temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            Struct s;
            // Struct s = initStruct(); // if you want to initialize with other values
            temp.push_back(s);
        }

        Matrix.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the types and your compiler issues an error :

```
typedef vector<Struct> Array; 

vector<Array> Matrix; // a vector of vectors

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    vector<Struct> temp;

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
       // temp[i].push_back(Matrix); -> wrong  
       // Matrix is a vector of vectors.
       // but temp is a vector of structs.
       temp.push_back(Struct()); 
    }

    Matrix.push_back(temp); //push the vector into the vector 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this type of mechanism to make 2D array of Structure.

```
vector < vector<Struct>> xyz;
vector<Struct> abc;

    //set value ++++++++
    Struct _st;
    _st.check = true;
    _st.display = NULL;
    _st.x = 10;
    _st.y = 10;
    //set value --------

abc.push_back(_st);
xyz.push_back(abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use resize() with a default row vector of default elements :

```
matrix.resize(rows,·vector<Struct>(cols));
```

Below an example in C++11, with a clear() before resize() in order to reinit with default values an already used matrix.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Struct {
    bool check = false;
    char display = '\0';
    int x = 0, y = 0;
};

void init_matrix(vector<vector<Struct>>& matrix, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    matrix.clear();
    matrix.resize(rows, vector<Struct>(cols));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ease your data handling, you can also assign the values through initialization of your struct, rather than a member at a time, e.g.

```
    std::vector<std::vector<Struct>> matrix;    /* declare matrix */

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {        /* loop ROWS times */
        std::vector<Struct> v;              /* declare vector of Struct */
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {    /* loop COLS times */
            Struct s = { 1, '*', i, j };    /* initialize struct */
            v.push_back (s);                /* push_back to vector */
        }
        matrix.push_back(v);    /* push back to matrix */
    }
```

Wrapping that in a short example, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define ROWS  10
#define COLS  ROWS

struct Struct {
    bool check;
    char display;
    int x,y;
};

int main (void) {

    std::vector<std::vector<Struct>> matrix;    /* declare matrix */

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {        /* loop ROWS times */
        std::vector<Struct> v;              /* declare vector of Struct */
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {    /* loop COLS times */
            Struct s = { 1, '*', i, j };    /* initialize struct */
            v.push_back (s);                /* push_back to vector */
        }
        matrix.push_back(v);    /* push back to matrix */
    }

    for (auto& i : matrix) {    /* auto-range loop over matrix  */
        for (auto& j : i)       /* auto-range loop over vectors */
            std::cout << j.x << ',' << j.y << "  check: " << j.check <<
                    "  display: '" << j.display << "'\n";
        std::cout << '\n';  /* tidy up with newline between vectors */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/vect2d_struct
0,0  check: 1  display: '*'
0,1  check: 1  display: '*'
0,2  check: 1  display: '*'
0,3  check: 1  display: '*'
0,4  check: 1  display: '*'
0,5  check: 1  display: '*'
0,6  check: 1  display: '*'
0,7  check: 1  display: '*'
0,8  check: 1  display: '*'
0,9  check: 1  display: '*'

1,0  check: 1  display: '*'
1,1  check: 1  display: '*'
1,2  check: 1  display: '*'
1,3  check: 1  display: '*'
1,4  check: 1  display: '*'
... <snip>
8,5  check: 1  display: '*'
8,6  check: 1  display: '*'
8,7  check: 1  display: '*'
8,8  check: 1  display: '*'
8,9  check: 1  display: '*'

9,0  check: 1  display: '*'
9,1  check: 1  display: '*'
9,2  check: 1  display: '*'
9,3  check: 1  display: '*'
9,4  check: 1  display: '*'
9,5  check: 1  display: '*'
9,6  check: 1  display: '*'
9,7  check: 1  display: '*'
9,8  check: 1  display: '*'
9,9  check: 1  display: '*'
```

Look things over and let me know if this is what you had intended, and if you have any further questions.